# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html

see below is my javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('auth').onclick=change;
function change(){
    this.className="account_holder";
}
</script>
```

html is

```
<td id="auth" class="authorised_reportericon" >
                        <a href="{% url incident.views.authorised_reporter %}">
                        <p align="center" style="color:black;font-size:16px;">Authorised Reporters</p></a>
                    </td>
```

I assigned td's id for onclick,but it is trowing error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: This is happening because the element with ID 'auth' does not exist.  Why? Because the DOM hasn't fully loaded to know about the element.  Use `window.onload = function() {}` and put your logic there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `document.getElementById('auth').onclick=change;` inside of `window.onload`, like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('auth').onclick=change;
};
```

According to the error you're getting, I'm guessing your Javascript is executed before your relevant HTML is rendered, meaning the element with the `id` "auth" isn't found. Putting it in an event where the whole DOM is ready should fix the problem.

Demo: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bYMDy/)

Comment: Hehe no problems, I had it set up (with just his code) as you posted the answer, I added your code to make sure, then thought I'd +1 you and add the link as you were right! :)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you've placed the script in the `head` of the document, which means it's running before the rest of the page has been rendered.

Instead, move it inside the `body`, to the very bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- your page content -->

        <!-- your script -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('auth').onclick=change;
        function change(){
            this.className="account_holder";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the elements will be available before the script runs. This is because the page renders in order from top to bottom, and scripts block the rendering when loading.

So when the script is in the head, it prevents the rest of the page below it from rendering until the script is complete, which means the `"auth"` doesn't yet exist.

Using this positioning technique of the script toward the end allows it to run potentially much sooner than waiting for a `window.onload` event.